# java project not working after ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am new in Java, spent on this problem too much time, can't solve it:

I run `build.xml` file in Eclipse Java project. Project successfully built, all tests passed, but after that project not working, seems to be that something wrong happens with .classpath file, cause if I change build path settings (e.g. delete libs and add again), everything works...

build.xml file
`

```
<!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
<!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
<property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="build" />
<property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
<property name="test.report.dir" location="test report" />

<!-- Define the classpath which includes -->
<path id="junit.class.path">

    <!-- needed libs -->
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-dbcp.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-pool.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/spring.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/spring-webmvc.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/standard.jar" />

    <!-- JUnit 3-4 -->
    <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100\junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100\junit.jar" />

    <!-- repository-config.xml -->
    <pathelement location="config" />

    <!-- classes after compiling -->
    <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
</path>

<!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
<target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
    </javac>
</target>

<!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\empdb.build.ant.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
    </jar>
</target>

<!-- Run the JUnit Tests -->
<!-- Output is XML, could also be plain-->
<target name="junit" depends="jar">
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="junit">
    <description>Main target</description>
</target>
```

`

This is the error on one of tests after project build

```
Class not found sef.test.repository.StubProjectRepositoryImplTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sef.test.repository.StubProjectRepositoryImplTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: What happens when you do `build clean` before each build?

Comment: Do you know where the sef.test.repository.StubProjectRepositoryImplTest class is? Is it one of your test classes? Or is it third party?

Comment: Yes, sef.test.repository.StubProjectRepositoryImplTest is in my project (one of my tests) and it works correctly, but after successfull project build with succesfull tests run this test not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often eclipse flips out when files changes.

Try this.

1. Right click your project and press refresh
2. Use Project -> clean... in eclipse
3. Use Project -> build all in eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your using Eclipse's build as the destination of your ant compile, so your workspace is out of sync after your ant compile target runs.

If the classpaths are the same between Eclipse and Ant, why do you need Ant's clean and compile targets?  If they're different, Ant should be compiling to a different destination.

If you really want Ant and Eclipse to compile to the same destination, tell Eclipse to refresh either by hitting F5 on the project root, or set the ant build configuration under external tools to refresh for you automatically:
[image]